# How does string builder replace work?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
    StringBuilder sbt = new StringBuilder(2);//
    System.out.print(sbt+"G");
    sbt.replace(0,2,"Mano");
    System.out.println(sbt+"Length is:"+sbt.capacity());
```

I expect it should print `GManoLength is:4`.

But it returns `GManoLength is:6`

How does this allocation work?

I read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#capacity())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not showing the *length* of the contents of the `StringBuilder`. You are showing the *capacity*. The StringBuilder can allocate however much space it wants to even if you never use that space. Usually it's a smart thing to assume StringBuilder will be used to add more data into it, otherwise you'd be using a String or other constant size construct.

If you want to show the *length* of the data, use `length()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` holds data in the `char[]` array under the hood and `capacity()` method returns the length of this array (not the length of appended values).

When the capacity is reached and you want to append more values then array should be extended. It's a good idea to give an extra space during this process and don't do extention after every append (it is expensive operation):

```
int newCapacity = value.length * 2 + 2;//called when capacity is reached during append
```

so `capacity` is always **bigger or equals** then the length of actual data (this value can be obtained by calling `length()` method)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to add this 4 characters "Mano" to a StrigBuilder of capacity 2, the method expandCapacity from AbstractStringBuilder will be called with minimumCapacity as the minimumSize needed to allocate the new string:

```
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = value.length * 2 + 2;
    if (newCapacity - minimumCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    if (newCapacity < 0) {
        if (minimumCapacity < 0) // overflow
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
}
```

The first thing that it tries to do is to double the current capacity and sum 2. Your original capacity is 2, so the newCapacity will be 6. This is greater that 4 (the length of "Mano") so that is the reason why you see 6.